# How to solve: $\int{\frac{r dr}{\sqrt{a r^2 + b r + c}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int{\frac{r dr}{\sqrt{a r^2 + b r + c}}}$$
But I don´t get the substitution trick that I have to perform. I've tried to:
$$
r^2 = x
$$
$$
2r dr = dx
$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a x + b \sqrt{x} + c}}}$$
But I also do not know how to solve this. I've also tried to do decomposition in simple fractions, but this won´t work because of the root. I would apreciate any hint on what variable change I should perform.

Comment: [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) rationalize all integral of that form and some.

Comment: $$\int{\frac{r \ dr}{\sqrt{a r^2 + b r + c}}}
=\frac1a \sqrt{a r^2 + b r + c}-\frac b{2a}
 \int{\frac{dr}{\sqrt{a r^2 + b r + c}}}
$$

Comment: Choices of substitutions depend on the conditions of the quadratic coefficients, a, b and c.

Comment: Do you know anything about the coefficients $a, b, c$, most importantly the values of the sign $\operatorname{sgn}(a)$ of $a$ and the discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c$? Those two values determine the character of the solution and, e.g., which trigonometric or Euler substitution is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try to write the integral in the form $$\int \frac{f'(x)dx}{ \sqrt{f(x)}}.$$
Here, your question, think which thing you have to multiply, divide , add and subtract to get the above form.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{mbrack}[3]{\left#1 #2  \right #3}$$
$$\newcommand{|}[1]{\mbrack{\lvert}{#1}{\rvert}}$$
first,factoring out the $a$ in the square root
$$\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{ar^2+br+c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}}}$$
let
$$I=\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}}}$$
since
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
then
$$\mbrack{(}{a+\frac{b}{2}}{)}^2=a^2+ab+\frac{b^2}{4}$$
completing the square
$$r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}=\mbrack{(}{r+\frac{b}{2a}}{)}^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}$$
let
\begin{align}
s&=\frac{b}{2a}\\
q&=\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}
\end{align}
$$I=\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{(r+s)^2+q}}$$
substituting
\begin{align}
t&=r+s\\
r&=t-s\\
dt&=dr
\end{align}
$$I=\int \frac{tdt}{\sqrt{t^2+q}}-s\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+q}}≝J_1-sJ_2$$
substituting again
\begin{align}
x&=t^2+q\\
dx&=2tdt\\
\frac{dx}{2}&=tdt
\end{align}
using the power rule and resubstituting
$$J_1=\frac{1}{2}\int x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx=\sqrt x=\sqrt{t^2+q}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(r+s)^2+q}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}}$$
factoring out the $\sqrt q$ and substituting
$$J_2=\sqrt q\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\mbrack{(}{\frac{t}{\sqrt{q}}}{)}^2+1}}$$
\begin{align}
u&=\frac{t}{\sqrt{q}}\\
du&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}dt\\
dt&=\sqrt q du
\end{align}
$$J_2=q\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$$
using a trig substitution
\begin{align}
u&=\tan(\theta)\\
du&=\sec^2(\theta)d\theta
\end{align}
using the trig identity and multiplying top and bottom by $\sec\theta + \tan\theta$
$$J_2=q\int \frac{\sec^2 \theta d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}}=q\int \sec\theta d\theta=q\int \frac{\sec\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)d\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}$$
let
\begin{align}
w&=\sec\theta+\tan\theta\\
dw&=(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\sec^2\theta)d\theta=\sec\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)d\theta
\end{align}
integrating and resubstituting
$$J_2=q\int\frac{dw}{w}=q\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{w}{\rvert}=q\ln\|{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}=q\ln\|{\sec(\tan^{-1}(u))+u}$$
let
\begin{align}
\varphi&=\tan^{-1}(u)\\
\tan(\varphi)&=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\
\alpha&=u\\
\beta&=1\\
\sec(\varphi)&=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}=\alpha^2+\beta^2=u^2+1
\end{align}
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the opposite,adjacent and hypotenuse side of the right triangle with angle $\varphi$ $$\\$$
continuing to resubstitute
$$J_2=q\ln\|{u^2+u+1}=q\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{\frac{t^2}{q}+\frac{t}{\sqrt q}+1}{\rvert}=q\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{\frac{1}{q}\mbrack{(}{t^2+\sqrt{q}t+q}{)}}{\rvert}\\=q\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{\frac{1}{q}\mbrack{(}{r^2+\mbrack{(}{\sqrt{q}+\frac{b}{a}}{)}r+s+q}{)}}{\rvert}=\mbrack{(}{\frac ca-\frac{b^2}{4}}{)}\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{r^2+\mbrack{(}{\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}}+\frac{b}{a}}{)}r+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{b}{2a}}{\rvert}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}}-\frac{b}{2a}\mbrack{(}{\frac ca-\frac{b^2}{4}}{)}\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{r^2+\mbrack{(}{\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}}+\frac{b}{a}}{)}r+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{b}{2a}}{\rvert}+K,a\ne0$$
$$\int\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{br+c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt b}\int\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{r+\frac{c}{b}}}$$
(where $K$ is an arbitrary constant) note that because there are divisions by $a$ ,therefore the above formula only works for $a\ne0$ $$\\$$
now doing the case for $a=0$
$$\xi=\int\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{r+\frac{c}{b}}}$$
\begin{align}
\tau&=r+\frac{c}{b}\\
d\tau&=dr
\end{align}
using the power rule
$$\xi=\int \frac{\tau d\tau}{\sqrt \tau}+\frac{c}{b}\int\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt \tau}=\frac{2}{3}\tau^{3/2}+\frac{2c}{b}\sqrt{\tau}=\frac{2}{3}\mbrack{(}{r+\frac{c}{b}}{)}^{3/2}+\frac{2c}{b}\sqrt{r+\frac{c}{b}}+K,b\ne0$$
again, since there are divisions by $b$ the above formula only works for $b\ne0$ $$\\$$ doing the case for $b=0$
$$\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt c}\int rdr=\frac{1}{2c}r^2+K$$
finally
$$\int \frac{rdr}{\sqrt{ar^2+br+c}}=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\sqrt a}\sqrt{r^2+\frac{b}{a}r+\frac{c}{a}}-\frac{b}{2a}\mbrack{(}{\frac ca-\frac{b^2}{4}}{)}\ln\mbrack{\lvert}{r^2+\mbrack{(}{\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}}+\frac{b}{a}}{)}r+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{b}{2a}}{\rvert}+K\hspace{15mm}&a\ne0\\\frac{2}{3\sqrt b}\mbrack{(}{r+\frac{c}{b}}{)}^{3/2}+\frac{2c}{b\sqrt b}\sqrt{r+\frac{c}{b}}+K &a=0,b\ne0\\\frac{1}{2c}r^2+K &a=0,b=0\end{cases}$$